# Toilets are broken. What can I do?

Tags: work-environment, united-kingdom

This morning I have arrived at the office to an email notification that the toilets in the building are to be used for liquids only due to a plumbing issue. There is no ETA for resolution.

The situation is beginning to get rather *uncomfortable*.
The office is in England.

I need to relieve myself and I cannot. Was does UK / EU employment law say about the provision of toilets for employees? Am I required to stay in the office if these facilities are not available?

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: What did your boss say when you asked her?

Comment: @JennyD i made the conscious decision to ask the internet before burdening my boss with my bowel movements. Professional courtesy mixed with shame.

Comment: @gusdor Wrong audience. Expect a much faster and more to-the-point answer from your boss than from 'the internet'.

Comment: I know this is not productive, but it's hilarious to me that this question is "on hold".

Comment: Is there a McDonald's nearby? Could you walk to a McDonald's? They typically provide clean toilets to the general public.

Comment: @Dana: It shouldn't be on hold. The OP has an urgent problem.

Comment: The OP can report that the problem was resolved without incident thanks to a diligent plumber. However, productivity for the morning took a large hit - as did the u-bend.

Comment: @JimG. I think that depends where you are (see McShit with Lies http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=McShit%20with%20lies) but the nearest McDs is a few miles up the road. A few colleagues went to a supermarket and came back looking less troubled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are specific laws in the UK regarding the number of (functional) toilets a workplace should have.

http://www.hse.gov.uk/contact/faqs/toilets.htm

I would suggest that you need to talk to your boss and explain to her that it is impractical to work in an environment without loos.

Possible solutions are

- Work from home.
- Use the loos at a nearby office, restaurant, etc. (if practical & the other building owner is ok with it).
- Close the building until the issue is fixed.

I would definitely report the issue to your local Health & Safety office.  I would also suggest that you talk to your union rep about the issue.  If you're not a member of a union - now's an excellent time to sign up!